# Scanning 35mm film with Epson 4490 in Ubuntu

Tags: scanner, epson

I have read the guides on downloading drivers for the Epson 4490 from Epson and Vuescan from Hamrick.com, but am unclear on whether Ubuntu will let me use the film scan utility?

Can anyone confirm I can use all the scan modes in Ubuntu with this scanner before I obliterate my Windows OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take a chance and install Ubuntu despite not getting the scanner up and running from the DVD.  It seems that was the problem.

After installation, I added the 3 .deb files above and it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm this yourself in about 20 minutes. I assume you already have a CD or USB from which to install from so just boot to it, select "Try Ubuntu", install the drivers and VueScan (yes, in the Live environment), and test it all out.

It'll be slower than a real install but you'll *know* and you won't touch a real hard disk. Everything will be done in RAM and when you reboot, nothing will persist.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know I could test this with the "try ubuntu" option. Thanks Oli.

Comment: I tried this, Vuescan seemed to install correctly and sees the scanner, but after trying to install the Epson software, I get errors in the software installation: dependency is not satisfiable: iscan-data. Vuescan tells me there is an Epson 4490 there, but then tells me I need to download from Epson. I'm new so apologies for my stupidity. I have tried searching the forums and google but can't get an answer.

Comment: Run sudo apt-get update and try again.

Comment: Thanks Oli, managed to get the software to install without errors but the vuescan app still will not recognize the drivers: ' VueScan found an Epson Perfection 4490, but no Epson software for this scanner was found on your system. Try downloading a driver for this scanner from www.epson.com '

Comment: I installed the three deb downloads: iscan-plugin-gt-x750_2.1.2-1_i386.deb ., iscan-data_1.26.0-1_all.deb ., and iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb and ran sudo apt-get update - ubuntu seems to know the scanner is there, but vuescan and imagescan tell me there is no scanner connected. I am running this from the dvd - could this be my problem?